# Tengo que pedir una cadena de texto y que la pegue en el document en mayusculas , minusculas y luego invertida (no van en orden) con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Tengo este codigo que me pide la cadena y no entiendo el porque solo me devuelve la misma cadena que he escrito y una sola vez.**

He puesto un `getElementById` que hace referencia al `<p>` que tiene el id `resultat`.
Luego he utilizado el `toUpperCase` y el `toLowerCase` para que el string se haga en minusculas y mayusculas y luego he hecho la function para invertir la cadena con una variable que guarda el string y un for con la variable inversor que es igual al length de la cadena introducida, y que se vaya restando uno cada vez que el bucle se vaya acabando hasta que llegue a 0 donde ya estará todo invertido.

```js
let cadenaDeText = prompt("Introdueix una cadena de text per tornarla al contrari,en mayuscules y misucules")
mayuscules();
minuscules();
invertString();



function mayuscules() {
  let strMayus = cadenaDeText.toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = strMayus;

}


function minuscules() {
  let strMinus = cadenaDeText.toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = strMinus;

}


function invertString() {
  let strInvert = "";

  for (let inversor = cadenaDeText.length - 1; inversor >= 0; inversor--) {
    strInvert += cadenaDeText[inversor]
  }
  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = strInvert;


}
```

```html
<p id="resultat"></p>
```

Comment: Hola Miguel, la idea es que en el `<p>` aparezca 3 veces la cadena, en minusculas, mayusculas e invertida, correcto?

Comment: Hola si efectivamente, tiene que salir tres veces da igual el orden de estos.

Comment: No entiendo, el codigo emite un error debido a que la variable strMinus solo tiene alcance dentro de la función minuscules() y tu la estas intentando utilizar dentro de invertString()

Comment: Ostras eso ha sido fallo del copy-paste quería poner la variable strInvert, el problema es que ahora solo se imprime la cadena invertida, pero no se imprime ni la cadena en mayúsculas ni en minúsculas.

Comment: Bro, estas haciendo el cambio sobre el mismo elemento html, en realidad si esta cambiando tu cadena para lo hace tan rapido como una computadora que solo estas viendo el ultimo resultado de la ultima función a ejecutar que es invertString(), ahora publico la respuesta

Comment: Ahhh claro ya entiendo, el problema es que necesito empezar a saber utilizar el getelementbyid y como no sabia como usarlo lo puse asi. Me harias un gran favor publicandola porque no tengo muy claro aun de como resolver el problema muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle es que es que sobrescribes la plantilla `<p>` cada que llamas tus funciones, se puede solucionar concatenando los resultados a una variable después de llamar a cada función.

```js
let cadenaDeText = prompt("Introdueix una cadena de text per tornar-la al contrari, en majúscules i minúscules");
let resultado = ""; //Agregamos la variable resultado

  mayuscules();
  minuscules();
  invertString();

  function mayuscules() {
    let strMayus = cadenaDeText.toUpperCase();
    resultado += "<p>" + strMayus + "</p>"
  }

  function minuscules() {
    let strMinus = cadenaDeText.toLowerCase();
    resultado += "<p>" + strMinus + "</p>";
  }

  function invertString() {
    let strInvert = "";
    for (let inversor = cadenaDeText.length - 1; inversor >= 0; inversor--) {
      strInvert += cadenaDeText[inversor];
    }
    resultado += "<p>" + strInvert + "</p>";
  }

  document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = resultado; //Actaulizamos el contenido HTML con el id de resultat con el valor de la variable resultado
```

```html
<p id="resultat"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que no estas concatenando el valor de la etiqueta `<p>` sino que la estas reemplazando en cada ejecución de tu función, el código debería quedar así

```js
let cadenaDeText = prompt("Introdueix una cadena de text per tornarla al contrari,en mayuscules y misucules");

//Declaramos una variable apunto al elemento html y ya no es necesario estar obteniendolo en cada función
let caja = document.getElementById("resultat");

mayuscules();
minuscules();
invertString();

/*

Fijate que en cada innerHTML, reemplazamos el simbolo "=" por "+=" que se refire a la concatenación,
quiere decir que al contenido que tiene la etiqueta p, le vamos a agregar una nueva cadena.

*/

function mayuscules() {
  let strMayus = cadenaDeText.toUpperCase();
  caja.innerHTML += strMayus+" " ;

}


function minuscules() {
  let strMinus = cadenaDeText.toLowerCase();
  caja.innerHTML += strMinus+" ";

}


function invertString() {
  let strInvert = "";

  for (let inversor = cadenaDeText.length - 1; inversor >= 0; inversor--) {
    strInvert += cadenaDeText[inversor]
  }
  caja.innerHTML += strInvert;


}
```

```html
<p id="resultat"></p>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me has resuelto bastantes dudas de como concatenar correctamente.